Issue with evaluating the residue at a double pole
I need to find the residue of the function
$f(z)=\frac{A(z)}{B{{(z)}^{2}}C(z)}$
at a zero ${{\bar{z}}_{B}}$ of $B(z)$. The functions $A(z)$, $B(z)$, and $C(z)$ are not elementary polynomials, and have fairly tedious expressions. The functions $B(z)$ and $C(z)$ have distinct sets of first order zeroes, and owing to the inverse-square dependency of $f(z)$ on $B(z)$, ${{\bar{z}}_{B}}$ is a second order pole of $f(z)$.
From the general expression for the residue at a pole of order $n$
$$\text{Res}\left( f,c \right)=\frac{1}{\left( n-1 \right)!}\begin{matrix}
   \lim   \\
   z\to c  \\
\end{matrix}\frac{\text{d}^{n-1}}{\text{d}z^{n-1}}\left[ {{\left( z-{{{\bar{z}}}_{B}} \right)}^{n}}f(z) \right]$$
the residue in this case noting that $n=2$ can be written as
$$ 
\text{Res}\left( f,{{{\bar{z}}}_{B}} \right)=\begin{matrix}
   \lim   \\
   z\to {{{\bar{z}}}_{B}}  \\
\end{matrix}\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}z}\left[ \frac{{{\left( z-{{{\bar{z}}}_{B}} \right)}^{2}}A(z)}{{{B}^{2}}(z)C(z)} \right]=\begin{matrix}
   \lim   \\
   z\to {{{\bar{z}}}_{B}}  \\
\end{matrix}\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}z}\left[ \frac{A(z)}{C(z)}\frac{{{\left( z-{{{\bar{z}}}_{B}} \right)}^{2}}}{{{B}^{2}}(z)} \right]
$$
With the Chain rule, this can be expanded as (upon cancelling $B(z)$ in the numerator and denominator of first term in brackets) as
$$
\text{Res}\left(f,\bar{z}_{B}\right)=\begin{matrix}
   \lim   \\
   z\to \bar{z}_{B}  \\
\end{matrix}\left[\frac{A}{C}\left( \frac{ z-\bar{z}_{B}}{B} \right)\left( \frac{2B-2\left( z-\bar{z}_{B} \right){B}'}{B^{2}} \right)+\frac{\left(z-\bar{z}_{B}\right)^{2}}{B^{2}}\left( \frac{C{A}'-A{C}'}{C^{2}} \right) \right]
$$
Noting that the limit of a product is the product of the limits, this yields
$$
 \text{Res}\left( f,{{{\bar{z}}}_{B}} \right)=\frac{A({{{\bar{z}}}_{B}})}{C({{{\bar{z}}}_{B}})}\left[ \text{ }\begin{matrix}
   \lim   \\
   z\to {{{\bar{z}}}_{B}}  \\
\end{matrix}\left( \frac{z-{{{\bar{z}}}_{B}}}{B} \right)\begin{matrix}
   \lim   \\
   z\to {{{\bar{z}}}_{B}}  \\
\end{matrix}\left( \frac{2B-2\left( z-{{{\bar{z}}}_{B}} \right){B}'}{{{B}^{2}}} \right) \right]+{{\left. \left( \frac{C{A}'-A{C}'}{{{C}^{2}}} \right) \right|}_{{{{\bar{z}}}_{B}}}}\begin{matrix}
   \lim   \\
   z\to {{{\bar{z}}}_{B}}  \\
\end{matrix}\left[ \frac{{{\left( z-{{{\bar{z}}}_{B}} \right)}^{2}}}{{{B}^{2}}} \right]
$$
The problem here is that the limit
$$
\begin{matrix}
   \lim   \\
   z\to {{{\bar{z}}}_{B}}  \\
\end{matrix}\left( \frac{2B-2\left( z-{{{\bar{z}}}_{B}} \right){B}'}{{{B}^{2}}} \right)
$$
invariably evaluates to infinity. Any pointers as to where I'm made a mistake would be deeply appreciated. Thanks in advance.

If $B$ has a pole of second order, then $B^2$ has a pole of fourth order.

I was proceeding with the understanding that the first order poles of $B(z)$ constitute second order poles of $f(z)$ owing to the inverse-square dependency of the latter on the former.

I fixed the incorrect verbiage in my post. Thanks for pointing that out.

I assume that you're referring to first order zeroes of $B$ and $C,$ rather than poles, yes?

Yes, I rather carelessly referred to them as second order poles when what I meant was that it is $f(z)$ that  has 2nd order poles, not $B(z)$.

You can do it with L'Hôpital's rule, which I recommend you use as early in your calculation as possible.

Incidentally, you're using far more curly brace symbols in your typesetting than you need.

L'Hospital's Rule will still yield an infinite limit with the problematic term. Unless there is a workaround, I cannot use L'Hospital's rule before I evaluate the derivative, and that's what yields the unresolvable $B^2(z)$ term in the denominator.

It works fine, viz.$$\frac{2B-2(z-\bar{z}_B)B'}{B^2}\sim\frac{(\bar{z}_B-z)B^{\prime\prime}}{BB'}\sim\frac{-B^{\prime\prime}}{B^{\prime2}}.$$

Cheap trick.
Expand all functions in their truncated Taylor series up to order two and then use a computer algebra system to find the residue of the quotient of these polynomials. You get the universal formula
$$(Res[f]=(a_1 b_1 c_0 - a_0 b_2 c_0 - a_0 b_1 c_1)/(b_1^3 c_0^2)$$ where e.g. the subscripted term $b_2 =B''(z_0)$ is the second derivative.

Thanks! I had just started down that path when I saw another post mention this approach.

Always noice to be able to answer one's own question!
The function
$$F(z)=\frac{A(z)}{B{{(z)}^{2}}C(z)}$$
can be expressed as
$$F(z)=\frac{f(z)}{g{(z)}}$$
where $f(z)=A(z)/C(z)$ and $g(z)=B^2(z)$.
The residue of $F(z)$ at the double pole $\bar{z}_B$ (a zero of $B(z)$) is therefore
$$\text{Res}[F(z)] ={\lim\\z\to\bar{z}_B}\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}z}\Big[\frac{(z-\bar{z}_B)^2}{g(z)}f(z)\Big]
$$
the function $g(z)$ can be expanded in a Taylor Series as
$$g(z)=g_o+g_1(z-\bar{z}_B)+g_2(z-\bar{z}_B)^2+\cdots$$
where
$$g_0 = B^2(\bar{z}_B)=0$$
$$
g_1 = \frac{\text{d}g}{\text{d}z}\Bigg|_{\bar{z}_B}
=2B(\bar{z}_B){B'}(\bar{z}_B)=0
$$
$$
g_2 = \frac{\text{d}^2g}{\text{d}z^2}\Bigg|_{\bar{z}_B}
=2{B'}(\bar{z}_B)^2
$$
and
$$
g_3 = \frac{\text{d}^3g}{\text{d}z^3}\Bigg|_{\bar{z}_B}
={B'}(\bar{z}_B){B''}(\bar{z}_B)
$$
Substitution of the above into the expression for the residue, differentiating and taking the limit results in
$$
\text{Res}[F(z)] =\frac{g_2f'(\bar{z}_B)-f(\bar{z}_B)g_3}{g_2^2}\\
=\frac{B'(\bar{z}_B)^2f'(\bar{z}_B)-f(\bar{z}_B){B'}(\bar{z}_B){B''}(\bar{z}_B)}{4B'(\bar{z}_B)^4}
$$
In the context of inverting a Laplace transform (where $e^{zt}$ is embedded in $A(z)$), whether this is a particularly efficient technique where $B(z)$ is itself a series expansion whose zeroes need to be evaluated numerically, is an entirely different issue!
